# Thread.sleep(long mills) delaying also previous method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, netbeans, jframe

```
invalid_login_label.setVisible(false);
username_label.setVisible(false);
user_field.setVisible(false);
password_label.setVisible(false);
pass_field.setVisible(false);

access_granted_label.setVisible(true);
Thread.sleep(1000);
this.dispose();
```

hello world! I'm kinda newbie to java and I'm using netbeans so I have this code in my jframe. what i want is to do is after the system authenticated the user. it will remove the visibility of all fields and display "access granted" for 1000mills but it starts delaying but still not removing the visibility of fields.

Comment: Google `Java Swing Thread.sleep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` does just that, it causes the current thread to sleep.  In this case I assume it's all done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, meaning that it is unable to update the screen, as you've stopped it from processing new events, like repaint events.

Swing is a single threaded environment, that is, all interactions and modifications to the state of the UI are expected to occur from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Anything which blocks this thread, such as extended I/O, long running loops or `Thread.sleep` will prevent the EDT from processing new events and updating the screen, making your application appear as if it has frozen...

Use a Swing `Timer` instead

For example...

```
invalid_login_label.setVisible(false);
username_label.setVisible(false);
user_field.setVisible(false);
password_label.setVisible(false);
pass_field.setVisible(false);

access_granted_label.setVisible(true);
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionListener(ActionEvent evt) {
        dispose();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details